# Lorentz contraction in sci-fi?

Tags: story-identification, spaceship, physics

In particular, I'd like to remember the title of a SF novel that I read a thousand years ago. Unfortunately I have forgotten almost every detail, except one that's stuck in my mind: after encountering many adventures, an interstellar spaceship returns to Earth. However, it carries its own reference frame with it, which differs from the terran frame. Scientists manage to pry open the ship's door and inside they find everything weirdly distorted (this is where the Lorentz contraction comes in).

Besides the title of that novel, I'd be interested to hear of any other SF novels or short stories where [Lorentz contraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_contraction) is used as a plot device!

Comment: I can't answer the question on the novel you are seeking. But to your second question, the middle of the book [The Science of Battlestar Galactica], composed of “The Physics of Battlestar Galactica” and “The Twelve Colonies and The Rest of Space” has chapters on relativity (E=mc2) and the Lorentz Contraction and how it is used in the series. http://www.amazon.com/Science-Battlestar-Galactica-Patrick-Justo/dp/0470399090

Comment: Open ended list questions - such as the latter half of yours - are off-topic for this site. The story identification part, on the other hand, is perfectly fine, so you should probably edit this to only include that aspect of it.

Comment: Arthur C. Clarke's story "Superiority" deals with the effects of localized space distortion, but I don't think he mentions Lorentz.

Answer (score 5):

Found it!

It's *Rogue Ship* by A.E. van Vogt. I had always suspected that it was one of his, but could not find it among [Wikipedia's bibliography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A._E._van_Vogt#Bibliography), nor among the individual plot summaries. So I decided to systematically follow the "external links" for each novel that seemed like a candidate. Eventually via a series of links I chanced upon the full text of *Rogue Ship* on a Russian web server. I won't link to it because I'm not sure it isn't a copyright violation!

Awesome hard sci-fi. The spaceship somehow manages to exceed the speed of light, although from Earth's perspective it is moving at a speed of only a thousand miles per hour relative to it. It returns to Earth on a collision course but instead of being smashed to smithereens on impact, it burrows into ground, barrels straight through and re-emerges unscathed hundreds of miles down course!

The ship's owner, who had sent it on its way six years earlier, forces his way inside the spaceship where he finds time slowed down to a near-standstill and everything, people included, severely compressed in the direction of travel. I don't know how scientifically accurate this is (probably not at all) but it's seriously mind-bending stuff. And Lorentz-Fitzgerald contraction does get mentioned explicitly several times.

Answer (score 2):

the lorentz contraction is a fundamental consequence of near light speed travel. it follows more or less the same law as time dilation ad mass increase with speed.
y=1/sqrt(1-v^2/c^2)    (where y is our lorentz factor)

M=my  (M is apparent mass at a given speed, m is rest mass, y is the factor, gamma, at that speed)

T=t/y   (T is time passed for the man on the starship, t is time passed for a stationary observer, y is gamma once again)

L=l/y  (L the apparent length when at speed, l the real length at rest, y  you guessed it)

this contraction is not observable to the moving person or someone flying alongside the starship as their rulers and any other length measuring equipment. they will also get the same length as the rest length if they try and measure the length with light beams. the contraction will only be noticeable to an observer watching the ship rush past at nearly light speed. onboard the ship the crew's view of the universe will be distorted by the contraction. when the ship comes to a halt after it's voyage it's length will be back to rest length.  there is no conceivable scenario in which scientists boarding a ship see it to be contracted because to board the ship it must stop or they must be travelling fast enough to dock with it.

Comment: The doesn't answer the question.